# Comparing Strings using Split , toCharArray and Equals methods

Tags: java, arrays, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to compare 2 Strings . I used split method and then `toCharArray` methods.

After all I used equals to, but at the end I get:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"

import java.util.Scanner;

public  class LoopsWiederholung {
public static void main (String [] args){

    System.out.print("Enter the first String : ");
    Scanner scan1  =  new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1  = scan1.next();
    s1.toUpperCase();

    System.out.print("Enter the second String : ");
    String s2 = scan1.next();
    s2.toUpperCase();
    String[] s3 = new String[100];
    s3 = s1.split("\\ ");

    String[] s4 = new String[100];
    s4 = s2.split("\\ ");

    for (int i = 0 ; i< 100 ; i++){
       if( s3[i].toCharArray().equals(s4[i].toCharArray())){
           System.out.print(s3[i]);
           }
       }


   }
}
```

Comment: Any special reason you're comparing your strings with `s3[i].toCharArray().equals(s4[i].toCharArray())`?  You can just compare them directly with `s3[i].equals(s4[i])`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Homework I guess

Comment: It may be helpful to instead compare if the two strings are equal using string1.equals(string2)

Comment: Arrays don't consider themselves equal to other arrays with the same content.

Comment: I thought @Omar would be a ghost

Comment: Actually I  am learning Java . I try to solve this with different methods . This is an exercise from a Java book . The exercise is so : Compare 2 strings print the equal words . So firstly i decided to split Strings to words . and then I tried so but it did not work . then i thought to use toCharArray method and then to compare the elements of these  arrays. But it did not work also.

Answer (score 0):

So many mistakes, so find my code with comments

```
    System.out.print("Enter the first String : ");
    Scanner scan1  =  new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1  = scan1.next();
    s1 = s1.toUpperCase();  // Strings are immutable

    System.out.print("Enter the second String : ");
    String s2 = scan1.next();
    s2 = s2.toUpperCase();

    // first check the lengths
    if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
        System.out.println("not the same");
        return;
    }

    String[] s3 = s1.split(""); // use this pattern

    String[] s4 = s2.split("");

    for (int i = 0 ; i< s3.length ; i++){
        if (s3[i].equals(s4[i]))
           System.out.print(s3[i]);
       }
   }
```

I am think that you either `split` to get an array of `Strings`, or use `toCharArray()` to compare `chars`

Comment: @khelwood No idea. Homework I guess.  Of course all of this code can easily be replaced with `if (s1.equals(s2)) System.out.println ("equal"));`  As I mention in my answer, there is also the use of toCharArray() to compare chars if that is what the homework should do

Answer (score 0):

The for loop iterates from 0 to 99, but it assumes that there are 99 elements in that array, so if there isn't you see an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

One fix may be to change:

`String[] s3 = s1.split("\\ ");`

and

`String[] s4 = s2.split("\\ ");`

So that the for loop can then be changed to:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i< s3.length(); i++){
    if(s3[i].equals(s4[i])){
        System.out.print(s3[i]);
    }
}
```

As @Scary Wombat mentioned, it is easier to compare two strings using `string1.equals(string2)` instead of checking character arrays.

Comment: *I am trying to compare 2 Strings* - not sure why the OP is splitting as he does.

Comment: I did what you have mentioned here . But it gives as output only one word . I mean I write 2 same sentences but it checks only first word and prints it